Input field in form with two different workflows
We have a form that user needs to input manually(at least for now).
Currently, we have an input field for users to type.
As we are planning to implement gen AI feature in our product,
we want to use it to fill out the form for user.
Yet, we would like to give user a choice of typing by themselves, which means we need to have two different workflows in one input field.
Possible options that I was considering;

Disable input field and display two buttons for each workflows as the top layer
Add toggle button next to the title of the input field,   to change the workflow
I am not sure if any of them are a good approach.

Is there any better user-friendly design?

There's a third way (if I understood the two you listed correctly):

Offer active input field plus the AI button (to left or right of field, depending on the overall layout of the form)

I'd see the plus here in the fact that the user needs no additional click to tell the system which way she wants to go: Typing into the field "activates" one flow, clicking the AI button the other one.
In addition, the design change required to add the IA feature is tiny and only adds exactly this feature. Adding a toggle button when you introduce the AI feature disrupts the overall form layout much more.

Thanks for sharing your idea. The reason I wanted to avoid that option was because of the consistency. In the other tab of the page, we want to implement the same feature in a similar workflow. However, there we specifically want to divide each workflow so that in manual flow, user can only use manual without AI available. I guess option 3 you mentioned can give the user an impression of being able to use AI even for manual workflow.

Then my question is - why don't you use the identical design on "this" page you're asking about? What is the rationale for the design choice on the "other" page? Oh, and welcome to the site - I overlooked this was your first question!

Thanks for welcoming! The 'other' page contains a simple table that user can add row from empty state. I am considering simply using two buttons for each workflow, while I am not sure whether I can apply the same approach to the 'form' page
